# How to read and write a virtual hard disk when it is opened by another application

Tags: vmware, virtualbox, virtual-pc

How to read and write a "virtual hard disk" when it is opened by "another application"?

virtual hard disk - referring to hard disk that are created by a virtualization application (e.g. Virtual PC, Virtual Box, VMware Player)

another application - referring to virtualization application (e.g. Virtual PC, Virtual Box, VMware Player)

Comment: what exactly is the goal ? sector-level-access ? filesystem-access ? what have you tried so far ? please show some source code...

Comment: @Yahia, there is currently no source code yet. the reason for such question is that I notice a write-lock is apply when the "virtual hard disk" is being opened by virtualization application and another application capable of reading virtual hard disk (e.g. Gizmo Central) will not be able to write or read data to it. probably either I write the code to write or read data ~or~ use a existing application capable of doing that.

Comment: the lock is in place for a reason: the VHD could be corrupted and/or the VM accessing it could crash if some prgram accesses it in parallel... the only "safe option" IMHO is to access it through the virtualization SW (some have an API) or expose it as a network share from inside the VM... all depends on you answers of the questions above (without the source)...

Comment: @Yahia, I know that the lock is in place for a reason and I know that the lock is very useful. However, I want the lock not to lock the whole virtual hard disk file. I want it to lock files that are being access in the virtual hard disk file so that I can access those files that are not locked in the virtual hard disk file... but would that be possible?

Comment: not the way you describe it, no... you can expose the VHD as a network share from within the VM and then access the files through that network share however...

Comment: @Yahia, ok. since there are currently no such solution, I will have to use the traditional methods - [1] Network or [2] Host-to-Guest file I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to be a staggeringly bad idea. Imagine if something in your computer started fiddling with the data on your disk as you were using it - things would end very poorly. And that's what you're asking here - the virtual machine is in operation, presumably, and you'd like to do something to its disk while it's in use. You'd be pulling the rug out from under the virtualized OS.

Read-only access, even, has many pitfalls - you'd need to assume that the data will be inconsistent, as the writes take time and are often spread out between sectors. If you read a sector as it's being written, it'll be useless data.

This is a tricky, but useful, thing to do if the VM isn't running. But it is, so can you communicate with it over the network? All three products you list have special host-to-guest file I/O capabilities that allow the guest to access files on the host, and vice-versa. Let the guest OS get or write your data.

Comment: Actually, if the virtualization application can lock files that are being accessed inside the virtual hard disk and allow read or copy of files that are not locked in the virtual hard disk, that will be good enough for me. Yes, I do agree that the alternative is using the special host-to-guest file I/O and the network communication.